# Accessing the record fields in Aura lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-components

I am trying to access the value of a field in the lightning aura component like below

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="TransferCase">
    <aura:attribute name="updateCase" type="Case" default="{'sobjectType':'Case'}"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
recordId="{!v.recordId}"
fields="Ready_for_Transfer__c"
targetFields="{!v.caseRecord}"
targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}"
/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.caseRecord.Ready_for_Transfer__c}">    
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Transfer Case" onclick="{!c.transferCase}"  />          
    <aura:set attribute="else">    
    <lightning:button disabled="true" variant="brand" label="Transfer Case" onclick="{!c.transferCase}"  />
```

Even though the Ready_for_Transfer__c is true on my case record it goes to the else condition here not sure if I am accessing the fields correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you fetching the Case record field value. Are you using force:recordData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: try adding-

```
<aura:attribute name="caseRecord" type="Object"/>
```

Comment: You should prefer Map instead of Object, though. Strange things can happen when using Object.