# Hide custom picklist field dependent on other picklist value in Aura?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

I am trying to hide picklist value field on aura component page. There is one picklist field called Registraction__c with Yes/No values. I am trying to control another field based on the values selected by user. If User selects Yes then User should be able to see Designation Label and its picklist values.

I have tried below so far but it's not working.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="GLOBAL" >
<aura:attribute name="Options" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="designationOptions" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:handler event="c:DataChangedEvent" action="{!c.activeButton}"/>
<aura:attribute name="isReadOnly" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
<lightning:combobox aura:id="fieldId" label="{!v.labelMap.Registration__c}" value="{!v.case.Registration__c}" options="{!v.Options}" required="true" onchange="{!c.activeButton}" disabled="{!v.isReadOnly}" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.case.Registration__c.value == 'No'}">
<lightning:combobox aura:id="fieldId" label="{!v.labelMap.Designation__c}" value="{!v.case.Account.Designation__c}" options="{!v.designationOptions}" required="true" onchange="{!c.activeButton}" disabled="{!v.isReadOnly}" />
</aura:if>
</lightning:layout>
```

below is the controller.js

```
({
activeButton: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.disableButton(cmp, false);
}
})
```

below is thehelper.js

```
({
disableButton: function(cmp, isDisable) {
    let savebtn = cmp.find('savebtn');
    savebtn.set('v.disabled', isDisable);
}
})
```

Comment: The field you're setting with the combobox (Case.Registration__c) isn't the same field you're using to control the aura:if statement (Case.NRD_Registration__).

Comment: Sorry, That's a typo happened while asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the fields of an Object, you should just reference the field itself not the field.value.

In this case, that would be:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.case.Registration__c == 'No'}"/>
```

You also need to include an attribute for tracking the Case record itself as well (as per [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375880/accessing-the-record-fields-in-aura-lightning-component) answer, which it doesn't currently look like you're doing:

```
<aura:attribute name="case" type="Map"/>
```

Alternatively, you could use a separate attribute to track if the additional picklist should be shown and update that in the onchange function of your first picklist. This approach would look something like this:

HTML:

```
<aura:attribute name="showPicklist" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showPicklist}">
    Picklist markup
</aura:if>
```

Controller:

```
({
activeButton: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    helper.disableButton(cmp, false);
    if(cmp.get("v.case.Registration__c" == "No"){
        cmp.set("v.showPicklist", true);
    }
}
})
```